# Importação de xml campo data

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo uma importação de tags de `xml` para campos do `textbox` em Windows Form, só que não estou conseguindo importar no formato correto os campos data, para um `masktextbox` no formato de data.Como tenho que proceder para mostrar no `textbox` a data no formato correto `dd/MM/aaaa`.

Segue meu código

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds.ReadXml(@"C:\Xml_Entrada\" + txt_chave.Text + ".xml");

txt_fornecedor.Text = ds.Tables["emit"].Rows[0]["xNome"].ToString();
txt_cnpj.Text = ds.Tables["emit"].Rows[0]["CNPJ"].ToString();
txt_nota.Text = ds.Tables["ide"].Rows[0]["nNF"].ToString();
txt_ie.Text = ds.Tables["emit"].Rows[0]["IE"].ToString();
txt_emissao.Text = ds.Tables["ide"].Rows[0]["dhEmi"].ToString();
txt_saida.Text = ds.Tables["ide"].Rows[0]["dhSaiEnt"].ToString();
```

Dados do Xml

```
<dhEmi>2018-06-15T09:56:51-03:00</dhEmi>

<dhSaiEnt>2018-06-15T09:56:51-03:00</dhSaiEnt>
```

Comment: Qual o formato que a data está vindo do xml?

Comment: Já tentou com `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`?

Comment: Editei a pergunta par colocar a data que esta vido do xml

Comment: Ja tentei Ricardo desta forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procure fazer desta forma:

```
// criar date time 2018-07-24 00:00:00.000
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2018, 7, 24, 00, 00, 00, 000);
String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dt);
```

Você pode ver mais sobre a formatação de DateTime em String [aqui](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/).

Comment: Thiago me explica uma coisa, estou fazendo do jeito que vc passou, mas como ainda sou novato em c#, não estou conseguindo passar o valor do dt para meu texbox da data, o meu textbox esta vazio no windowsform

Comment: Da forma que eu falei, os dados para o xml estão indo de forma correta? E um outro problema seu, é que o valor da data não está sendo exibido no campo do `textbox`?

Comment: Isso mesmo o valor não exibe no meu textbox. txt_emissao.text = dt

Comment: Muito obrigado Thiago consegui aqui passar o valor para o textbox. Obrigado pela ajuda.